# Auth/Capture Chained Payment (PayPal)

Tags: paypal, authorization, capture, paypal-adaptive-payments

Background:

We run a company that connects producers and consumer together. Consumers request certain objects to be created by producers. A producer would have to confirm that they are available and capable to produce the object. We are using Chained Payments to take a service fee. We (the company) are the Primary while the Producer is the secondary.

Problem:

What happens if the producer is unavailable for production? Can the producer "reject" a payment and automatically refund the consumer?

Approach - Auth/Capture:

We can use Auth/Capture to temporarily hold the consumer's funds during a 48 hour window. During this 48 hour period, the producer would have to confirm (via a button) whether or not they can complete the task. By clicking the button, Paypal would have to automatically execute/reject the payment. Is this possible? I am getting stumped on the subject of having a button, outside the Paypal Environment, to initiate a transaction within the Paypal API. Also note, that if the Producer does not respond within 48 hours, the payment will have to be automatically rejected.

Really stumped here - hope you guys can help out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you would want to use for this is Preapproved Payments.  You'll use the Preapproval API to generate a preapproval profile for the payer. Then when everything that needs to happen for a payment to take place happens you can use the Pay API with the preapproval code to submit the payment accordingly.